# Stored procedure giving error while implementing

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

While implementing the procedure I am getting errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GET_USER_REPORT_DATA, Line 19
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GET_USER_REPORT_DATA, Line 23
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Here is the procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_USER_REPORT_DATA]
    @From_Date datetime,
    @To_Date datetime
AS
BEGIN
    Select *
    into #GetUserTable
    from
        (select distinct 
             a.N_UserMkey, b.mkey,
             ISNULL(b.first_name + ' ' , '') + ISNULL(b.last_name,'') NAME
         from 
             inward_doc_tracking_trl AS a
         inner join  
             user_mst AS b on a.N_UserMkey = b.mkey
         where 
             a.U_datetime between @From_Date and @To_Date

         select distinct 
             a.mkey, b.ref_mkey
         from 
             inward_doc_tracking_hdr AS a
         inner join 
             inward_doc_tracking_trl AS b on a.mkey = b.ref_mkey 
                                          and a.U_datetime between @From_Date and @To_Date
        ) as xx

    SELECT * FROM #GetUserTable

    DROP TABLE #GetUserTable
END
```

Comment: i think you may forgot to put union or join between two your select statement in your inner query

Comment: @navnit: I already tried with `union` but it was asking `All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists`

Comment: exactly your first query returns three fields and your second query returns two fields. it must be eqal in both query if you want to use union

Comment: so what should I do make it one query but add the `mkey` from the second query into the first table. any idea ?

Comment: see, if I run with first query, i will get 3 columns. i  just only want one more column to be added which is mkey from the `inward_doc_tracking_hdr` table

Comment: @N K, add an `INNER JOIN` to your first query to join inward_doc_tracking_hdr to inward_doc_tracking_trl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this, also see my comment

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_USER_REPORT_DATA]
    @From_Date datetime,
    @To_Date datetime
AS
BEGIN

    Select *
    --into #GetUserTable   --Try to never use temp table. Here no need to use temp table
    from
        (
            select distinct a.N_UserMkey, b.mkey,
                ISNULL(b.first_name + ' ' , '') + ISNULL(b.last_name,'') NAME
            from inward_doc_tracking_trl AS a
                inner join user_mst AS b on a.N_UserMkey = b.mkey
            where a.U_datetime between @From_Date and @To_Date
            union
            select distinct a.mkey, b.ref_mkey ,'' NAME   -- In your union tale, if you add runtime column then add value based on your datatype. If you add in first query, then name must give, but if you query is second or third then not compulsory
            from inward_doc_tracking_hdr AS a
                inner join inward_doc_tracking_trl AS b
                        on a.mkey = b.ref_mkey and a.U_datetime between @From_Date and @To_Date
        ) as xx

        --SELECT * FROM #GetUserTable
        --DROP TABLE #GetUserTable
END
```

Comment: tried your query but first row value coming blank http://s33.postimg.org/914vf1svz/image.png

Comment: this means no data there. right? if no, then give some data

Answer (score 0):

i think you may forget to put union between two your select statement in your inner query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_USER_REPORT_DATA]
@From_Date DATETIME ,
@To_Date DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  *
    INTO    #GetUserTable
    FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT
                        a.N_UserMkey ,
                        b.mkey ,
                        ISNULL(b.first_name + ' ', '')
                        + ISNULL(b.last_name, '') NAME
              FROM      inward_doc_tracking_trl a
                        INNER JOIN user_mst b ON a.N_UserMkey = b.mkey
              WHERE     a.U_datetime BETWEEN @From_Date AND @To_Date
              UNION
              SELECT DISTINCT
                        a.mkey ,
                        b.ref_mkey ,
                        ISNULL(c.first_name + ' ', '')
                        + ISNULL(c.last_name, '') NAME
              FROM      inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
                        INNER JOIN inward_doc_tracking_trl b ON a.mkey = b.ref_mkey
                                                          AND a.U_datetime BETWEEN @From_Date AND @To_Date
                        INNER JOIN user_mst c ON c.N_UserMkey = b.mkey
            ) AS xx   


    SELECT  *
    FROM    #GetUserTable
    DROP TABLE #GetUserTable
END
```

Comment: i dont have first_name, last_name in `inward_doc_tracking_trl` table. its in `user_mst` table